# How to use FileHelpers with records with a hierarchical structure?

Tags: c#, csv, hierarchical-data, filehelpers

I have a class like this

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private List<string> _bar = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { _bar = value; }
    }
}
```

My .csv file looks like this:

```
Foo;Bar
A;B
A;C
```

So I want to have a Foo object with Name "A" and a Bar-list (or an array) with "B" and "C".

Is it possible to simply parse my .csv file with FileHelpers? Or some other library? Don't bother to create a more complex solution (with for-loops or so) with a 3rd party tool. Then I will create a standard solution with .NET.

Answer (score 0):

So your FileHelpers class should look like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class FooSpec
{
    public string Name;
    public string Bar;
}
```

Read all the records into an array and adjust with Linq.

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<FooSpec>();
// ReadFile returns an array of Foo
var records = engine.ReadFile(filename);

var fooRecords = list
             .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
             .Select(x => 
                new Foo() { 
                  Name = x.Key, 
                  Bar = x.Select(y => y.Bar).ToList() 
                });
```